# How do I import named exports from a library bundled with Rollup into a HTML page?

Tags: javascript, bundling-and-minification, rollupjs

I'm probably just incorrect about my assumptions of how this should work, so I would appreciate it if somebody can either tell me what to change in my Rollup config or how I should use the resulting bundle.

Let me set the scene. I'm writing a library, bundling it with Rollup, and then want to write some HTML page where I import a named export from that libray. It keeps telling me that it can't find the named export.

For your convenience, I have boiled the issue down to this minimal example:

I have The following files in my project folder:

- `min-example.js`:

```js
export function minExample(){
  return "can you find me?";
}
```

- `package.json`:

```json
{
  "name": "min-example",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "A minimal example of an issue with rollup",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "rollup -c"
  },
  "author": "nvcleemp",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "rollup": "^2.58.0"
  }
}
```

- `rollup.config.js`

```js
export default [
  {
    input: "min-example.js",
    output: {
      file: `min-example.bundle.js`,
      name: "min-example",
      format: "umd"
    }
  }
];
```

If I run `npm run build`, then this creates the file `min-example.bundle.js`:

```js
(function (global, factory) {
  typeof exports === 'object' && typeof module !== 'undefined' ? factory(exports) :
  typeof define === 'function' && define.amd ? define(['exports'], factory) :
  (global = typeof globalThis !== 'undefined' ? globalThis : global || self, factory(global["min-example"] = {}));
})(this, (function (exports) { 'use strict';

  function minExample(){
    return "can you find me?";
  }

  exports.minExample = minExample;

  Object.defineProperty(exports, '__esModule', { value: true });

}));
```

I would have expected that I could use this file in the following manner:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Minimum example</title>
</head>

<body>
        <script type="module">
        import { minExample } from './min-example.bundle.js';

        console.log(minExample());
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

As I said above however, this complains that it can't find the named export `minExample`.

Note that it does work without using Rollup:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Minimum example</title>
</head>

<body>
        <script type="module">
        import { minExample } from './min-example.js';

        console.log(minExample());
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, a bit more trial-and-error let to a solution. Apparently the output format should be `es` instead of `umd`, so the file `rollup.config.js` had to be changed to

```js
export default [
  {
    input: "min-example.js",
    output: {
      file: `min-example.bundle.js`,
      name: "min-example",
      format: "es"
    }
  }
];
```

So I was indeed under the false impression that `umd` just combined `es` and `cjs`.